# completely remove the favicon from Vue app

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I currently don't have a favicon for my Vue app and want to remove the default one. I commented out the relevant line in the `public/index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico" /> -->
    <title>My Vue app</title>
  </head>
  <!-- ... body code ... -->
</html>
```

and run `npm run serve`. The page still renders the initial favicon. How can I remove it?

Comment: Did you delete the favicon.ico file? Browsers will automatically detect it if they can even if you don't have the link element in your `head` element. Otherwise the browser may have cached the file when you ran the server to begin with. Open up your site in incognito mode to check if that is the case.

Comment: yeah, I had to clear the cache and delete the file :)

Comment: if you want to you can post your comment as an answer

Comment: WHy is it that even in my incognito mode, still vue favicon renders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when this happens it's one of two things

1. Most browsers will check for a file called `favicon.ico` in the root folder and use it even if you don't include it in your `head` tag.
2. If the file has been deleted but you had previously opened the website then it's likely just cached in your browser. You can easily check by opening the site in incognito/private browsing mode. Clearing your browser cache for the website will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after trying to change my favicon and failed, I added this line after inspecting vuejs `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/favicon.png">`, whereby, this time, `favicon.png` was targeting my own image.